# Python error "unbound method must be called with instance as first argument"

Tags: python, class, oop, syntax-error

It's high time I start using Classes. I have always found another way. Yesterday I found exactly the code I need, but it's in a nice little Class and I can't figure out how to access it. I've read all the tutorials and even similar solutions here. I just can't wrap my head around it. The only part I wrote, is "main()" which is the part that doesn't work. I have re-written main a few dozen ways, and none of them work the way I expect them to work.

Thank you for your time, and patience.

All credit goes to Nathan Adams - aka dinnerbone

```
import socket
import struct

class MinecraftQuery:
    MAGIC_PREFIX = '\xFE\xFD'
    PACKET_TYPE_CHALLENGE = 9
    PACKET_TYPE_QUERY = 0
    HUMAN_READABLE_NAMES = dict(
        game_id     = "Game Name",
        gametype    = "Game Type",
        motd        = "Message of the Day",
        hostname    = "Server Address",
        hostport    = "Server Port",
        map         = "Main World Name",
        maxplayers  = "Maximum Players",
        numplayers  = "Players Online",
        players     = "List of Players",
        plugins     = "List of Plugins",
        raw_plugins = "Raw Plugin Info",
        software    = "Server Software",
        version     = "Game Version",
    )

    def __init__(self, host, port, timeout=10, id=0, retries=2):
        self.addr = (host, port)
        self.id = id
        self.id_packed = struct.pack('>l', id)
        self.challenge_packed = struct.pack('>l', 0)
        self.retries = 0
        self.max_retries = retries

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.socket.settimeout(timeout)

    def send_raw(self, data):
        self.socket.sendto(self.MAGIC_PREFIX + data, self.addr)

    def send_packet(self, type, data=''):
        self.send_raw(struct.pack('>B', type) + self.id_packed + self.challenge_packed + data)

    def read_packet(self):
        buff = self.socket.recvfrom(1460)[0]
        type = struct.unpack('>B', buff[0])[0]
        id = struct.unpack('>l', buff[1:5])[0]
        return type, id, buff[5:]

    def handshake(self, bypass_retries=False):
        self.send_packet(self.PACKET_TYPE_CHALLENGE)

        try:
            type, id, buff = self.read_packet()
        except:
            if not bypass_retries:
                self.retries += 1

            if self.retries < self.max_retries:
                self.handshake(bypass_retries=bypass_retries)
                return
            else:
                raise

        self.challenge = int(buff[:-1])
        self.challenge_packed = struct.pack('>l', self.challenge)

    def get_status(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'challenge'):
            self.handshake()

        self.send_packet(self.PACKET_TYPE_QUERY)

        try:
            type, id, buff = self.read_packet()
        except:
            self.handshake()
            return self.get_status()

        data = {}

        data['motd'], data['gametype'], data['map'], data['numplayers'], data['maxplayers'], buff = buff.split('\x00', 5)
        data['hostport'] = struct.unpack('<h', buff[:2])[0]
        buff = buff[2:]
        data['hostname'] = buff[:-1]

        for key in ('numplayers', 'maxplayers'):
            try:
                data[key] = int(data[key])
            except:
                pass

        return data

    def get_rules(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'challenge'):
            self.handshake()

        self.send_packet(self.PACKET_TYPE_QUERY, self.id_packed)

        try:
            type, id, buff = self.read_packet()
        except:
            self.retries += 1
            if self.retries < self.max_retries:
                self.handshake(bypass_retries=True)
                return self.get_rules()
            else:
                raise

        data = {}

        buff = buff[11:] # splitnum + 2 ints
        items, players = buff.split('\x00\x00\x01player_\x00\x00') # Shamefully stole from https://github.com/barneygale/MCQuery

        if items[:8] == 'hostname':
            items = 'motd' + items[8:]

        items = items.split('\x00')
        data = dict(zip(items[::2], items[1::2]))

        players = players[:-2]

        if players:
            data['players'] = players.split('\x00')
        else:
            data['players'] = []

        for key in ('numplayers', 'maxplayers', 'hostport'):
            try:
                data[key] = int(data[key])
            except:
                pass

        data['raw_plugins'] = data['plugins']
        data['software'], data['plugins'] = self.parse_plugins(data['raw_plugins'])

        return data

    def parse_plugins(self, raw):
        parts = raw.split(':', 1)
        server = parts[0].strip()
        plugins = []

        if len(parts) == 2:
            plugins = parts[1].split(';')
            plugins = map(lambda s: s.strip(), plugins)

        return server, plugins

def main():
    check = MinecraftQuery.get_status('10.0.10.8',25565)
    print check

main()
```

Comment: You need to instantiate the class before calling a method in it. First make a new instance by using MinecraftQuery(host, port), where host and port are obviously the host and port names. Then call the status on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be as follows. Try and see if it works.

```
def main():
    check = MinecraftQuery('10.0.10.8', 25565)
    # It calls the __init__() method and constructs an object/instance of the class named 'MinecraftQuery'
    # using the given arguments and associate it with the given identifier 'check'
    check.get_status()
    # Now, this invokes the get_status() method of the instance named 'check'.
    print check
```

Comment: Yes! I no longer get an error in main(). Now I have timeout errors waiting for packets. I need to tweak this for a different version of minecraft. Thank YOU!

Answer (score 0):

An unbound method is one that is not called with an instance of a class. Your error means that you are calling the method on the class rather than on an instance. So, you should first create an instance of the class and then call the method.